# C++ constexpr for polynomial evaluation with Horner's method

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I have want to be able go evaluate the derivative of a polynomial using Horner's method and use the result as a `constexpr`. This seems incredibly mundane, but I am missing something obvious because the compiler says that I am exceeding maximum recursion depth. The core recursion happens here:

```
template<size_t d, size_t i, typename C, typename X>
constexpr X evalImpl(const C &c, const X &x) {
    return i >= (C::SizeAtCompileTime - 1 - d) ? 1 : evalImpl<d, i + 1, C, X>(c, x);
}
```

You should not need to even know Horner's method to know what it is going on here, so I have stripped the code as much as possible, even removing how `x` is used, because it does not seem relevant to the problem I am having.

The idea is that when an index `i` equals the degree of the polynomial `Degree<C>::value` minus the order of the derivative `d`, then the recursion should stop. Otherwise, it should increment the index `i` and try again.

I am calling the above recursion with a call of the form

```
 eval<derivative, 0>(c, x)
```

where `c` is an Eigen Matrix of type `Eigen::Matrix<double,1,7>`, and `x` is a double. The idea is to start at 0 and count up to essentially the degree of the polynomial.

The compiler error message is of the form

```
In file included from /mnt/c/proj/src/main.cpp:11:0:
/mnt/c/proj/src/polynomial.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr X {anonymous}::evalImpl(const C&, const X&) [with long unsigned int d = 1ul; long unsigned int i = 898ul; C = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 7>; X = double]':
/mnt/c/proj/src/polynomial.h:74:108:   recursively required from 'constexpr X {anonymous}::evalImpl(const C&, const X&) [with long unsigned int d = 1ul; long unsigned int i = 1ul; C = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 7>; X = double]'
/mnt/c/proj/src/polynomial.h:74:108:   required from 'constexpr X {anonymous}::evalImpl(const C&, const X&) [with long unsigned int d = 1ul; long unsigned int i = 0ul; C = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 7>; X = double]'
/mnt/c/proj/src/polynomial.h:109:39:   required from 'constexpr X Polynomial::eval(const C&, const X&) [with long unsigned int d = 1ul; C = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 7>; X = double]'
/mnt/c/proj/src/main.cpp:306:66:   required from here
/mnt/c/proj/src/polynomial.h:74:108: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
         return i >= (C::SizeAtCompileTime - 1 - d) ? 1 : evalImpl<d, i + 1, C, X>(c, x);
```

Comment: I don't follow. The degree of the polynomial is 7. This should not be evaluating more than 7 times

Comment: Generally, this code will not be used to generate compile time expressions. Most of the time, I will use it with doubles. However, there are instances where we will need the output as a template parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition here:

```
return i >= (C::SizeAtCompileTime - 1 - d) ? 1 : evalImpl<d, i + 1, C, X>(c, x);
```

is not a `if constexpr`. Thus no matter whether `i >= (C::SizeAtCompileTime - 1 - d)` is `true` or `false`, the remaining one will always be instantiated. Thus recursion won't stop as you want.

Change to this:

```
if constexpr (i >= (C::SizeAtCompileTime - 1 - d)) {
    return 1;
} else { 
    return evalImpl<d, i + 1, C, X>(c, x);  
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't have access to C++17, use tag dispatch:

```
template<size_t d, size_t i, typename C, typename X>
constexpr X evalImpl_impl(const C &c, const X &x, std::true_type) {
    return 1;
}

template<size_t d, size_t i, typename C, typename X>
constexpr X evalImpl_impl(const C &c, const X &x, std::false_type) {
    return evalImpl_impl<d, i + 1, C, X>(c, x, std::integral_constant<bool, C::SizeAtCompileTime-1-d <= i+1>{});
}

template<size_t d, size_t i, typename C, typename X>
constexpr X evalImpl(const C &c, const X &x) {
    return evalImpl_impl(c, x, std::integral_constant<bool, C::SizeAtCompileTime-1-d <= i>{});
}
```

Comment: Tenary operators are not constexpr?

Comment: @bremen_matt 2 branches should both be instantiated. Short-circuit only affects run-time evaluation, not instantiation.

Comment: Is this C++11? or 14?

Comment: @bremen_matt `if constexpr` is C++17. Your approach with tenary operator won't work for any version.

Comment: I had been trying unsuccessfully to use template specialization to break this into two functions, one with the stopping conditions. I guess I will have to switch back to that approach. I need C++11